# Python SSL error bad handshake when using pydata_google_auth

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I am trying to move data from SQL server to Google Bigquery using Python

When I run the below code in python I get a **SSL Error Bad Handshake**

```
credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
SCOPES,
auth_local_webserver=True,
)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=xxx): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

I have tried downgrading/upgrading all google cloud packages.
I have also tried the below command but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', verify=False)
```

I am not able to find any fixes for this. Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Which version of Python? Which OS? Your certificates authorities collection (package) is probably out of date.

Comment: I am using Python 3.8 and Windows 10. How do I update the certificates? Thanks